# Fetch serial port output in python

Tags: python, sql-server, serial-port, sql-server-2017

I'm new to the Python. I have a python code with me and my goal is to fetch serial output, then store the output into Microsoft SQL database.

This serial output below will appear every time when students scan fingerprint to take attendance, this is what Arduino serial monitor shows on the screen:

```
{'SID':1,'Date':2018/11/17,'Time':07:11:13}
{'SID':2,'Date':2018/11/17,'Time':07:15:41}
....
....
```

I would like to let my python code to do the job, which is fetching the serial output above and store into Microsoft SQL database. When students scan fingerprint to take attendance, the python should be able to fetch serial output and store it into MSSQL every single time. I do it like this:

```
import pyodbc
import serial
import time
import datetime
import ast
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=DESKTOP-H7KQUT1;"
                      "Database=SAOS1;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=.1) 

while True:
        data = arduino.readline()[:-2].decode("utf-8") 
        if data!="":
                SID = ast.literal_eval(data)['SID']
                Atd_Date = ast.literal_eval(data)['Date']
                Atd_InTime = ast.literal_eval(data)['Time']

        print ('Inserting a new row into table')
        tsql = "INSERT INTO attendance (Atd_Date, Atd_InTime, SID) VALUES (?,?,?);"
        with cursor.execute(tsql,Atd_Date,Atd_InTime,SID):
                print ('Successfuly Inserted!')
```

However, I failed to do it. The python code above is not really working as expected. I got this error as well:

> with cursor.execute(tsql,Atd_Date,Atd_InTime,SID):
>   NameError: name 'Atd_Date' is not defined

Comment: How about increasing the indent of the last 4 lines?

Comment: @kunif What do you mean increasing the indent? I'm pretty new to the python, may need some example though

Comment: The scope of Atd_Date, Atd_InTime, SID appears to be accessible only within the if block. Since the last four lines are outside the if block, Atd_Date, Atd_InTime, and SID will be in a discarded state. If you deepen the indentation so that the last 4 lines are executed only in the if block, it is considered that the error will disappear.

Comment: @kunif Yup, I've put the last 4 lines within if block, I'm not getting that error again. But nothing happen when I tried to scan fingerprint. Data cannot push to MSSQL

Comment: Since I am not familiar with databases, I will only refer to general knowledge.  Please set up so that pyodbc's behavior can be logged and investigate the situation.

Comment: Also see my answer re commit...

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set autocommit to true, or commit your change after executing the cursor...